# How to print a list of ggplots to an animated GIF?

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2

I have a list of jitter plots created using `geom_jitter()` method. How can I print the list as an animated GIF? Although, I can easily print them as a pdf.

I saw some posts where users have created the animation using a function, but I don't have a function, just a list.

```
p1 <- ggplot(Test, aes(x=factor(Wavelength, level = level_order), y=Reflectance, color=SDS.y)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=SDS.y), alpha = 0.3, width = 0.3) +
  labs(title = "Threshold (Healthy = 0-5, Diseased = 6-100)", x = "Wavelength", y = "Reflectance") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 1)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("purple", "red3")) +
  facet_grid(Rotation~Date)

#Printing all plots to 1 pdf file

Plots = list(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19)
pdf("Jitter Plots.pdf", width = 25, height = 8.5)
Plots
dev.off()
```

[Here is the sample animated GIF that I am expecting. However, I created this simply by converting pdf to GIF.](https://twitter.com/i/status/1166903554642239490)